Get the Network Provider details (SIM info) from iPhone using my iOS App, swift, xcode?
I am creating an app where i need to show user some details from the network provider in the iPhone such as ICCID, or phone number etc
This is my current code
let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
if let carrier = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.values.first {
     print("Carrier Name: \(carrier.carrierName ?? "Unknown")")
     print("Mobile Country Code: \(carrier.mobileCountryCode ?? "Unknown")")
     print("Mobile Network Code: \(carrier.mobileNetworkCode ?? "Unknown")")
     print("ISO Country Code: \(carrier.isoCountryCode ?? "Unknown")")
     print("Allows VOIP: \(carrier.allowsVOIP)")
} else {
     print("No carrier information available")
}

and receiving default values
Carrier Name: --
Mobile Country Code: 65535
Mobile Network Code: 65535
ISO Country Code: --
Allows VOIP: true


Apps  do not have access to this information.
